# Погода за прошедшие дни через API

Tags: yandex-maps-api, google-api

Хочу средствами API узнать погоду, причём не ту, что будет, а ту, что была, желательно через Google или Яндекс. Но вот найти команду не могу. На сегодня данные есть, прогнозы есть, а вот чтобы за определённый прошедший день в определённом городе — нету.

Подскажите, где брать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Про Яндекс лучше сразу забыть. У Яндекс Погоды нет **официального** открытого API.

Однако такой API есть у многих сервисов погоды. Например, [OpenWeatherMap](http://openweathermap.org/history). Это сервис приведён просто в качестве примера и как возможный вариант. Если не подойдёт, можно воспользоваться другим.